# ruby DateTime parsing from 'mm/dd/yyyy' format

Tags: ruby

I am using `ruby 1.9.3` and want to get `Date or Time` object from '`mm/dd/yyyy`' date `format` string

```
Time.zone.parse("12/22/2011")
```

this is giving me `*** ArgumentError Exception: argument out of range`

Answer (score 155, accepted):

```
require 'date'
my_date = Date.strptime("12/22/2011", "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Answer (score 22):

As above, use the strptime method, but note the differences below

```
Date.strptime("12/22/2011", "%m/%d/%Y") => Thu, 22 Dec 2011
DateTime.strptime("12/22/2011", "%m/%d/%Y") => Thu, 22 Dec 2011 00:00:00 +0000
Time.strptime("12/22/2011", "%m/%d/%Y") => 2011-12-22 00:00:00 +0000
```

(the +0000 is the timezone info, and I'm now in GMT - hence +0000. Last week, before the clocks went back, I was in BST +0100. My application.rb contains the line config.time_zone = 'London')

Answer (score 7):

Try `Time.strptime("12/22/2011", "%m/%d/%Y")`

Answer (score 4):

Would it be an option for you to use `Time.strptime("01/28/2012", "%m/%d/%Y")` in place of Time.parse? That way you have better control over how Ruby is going to parse the date.

If not there are gems: (e.g. ruby-american_date) to make the Ruby 1.9 Time.parse behave like Ruby 1.8.7, but only use it if it's absolutely necessary.

```
1.9.3-p0 :002 > Time.parse '01/28/2012'
ArgumentError: argument out of range

1.9.3-p0 :003 > require 'american_date'
1.9.3-p0 :004 > Time.parse '01/28/2012'
 => 2012-01-28 00:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: One more thing ruby 1.9.3 The to_time conversion now accepts %d,%m,%Y as the string format "29/10/2013".to_time => 2013-10-29 00:00:00 UTC