# Ruby on Rails, filter results from date_from, date_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, search

I am trying to implement as search function on my site, which will search a database for entries with dates that match the params: date_from and date_to.

This is my form to grab the params containing date_from and date_to:

```
<div class="row">
  <h4 class="text-center mt-4">Alle vagter</h1>
    <div class="pull right rage-query">
      <%= form_tag admin_shifts_search_path, method: :get do %>
      <%= text_field_tag 'search[date_from]', @search.date_from %>
      <%= text_field_tag 'search[date_to]', @search.date_to %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: "btn search-button" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

My shifts_search action:

```
def shifts_search
  @search = ShiftSearch.new(params[:search])
  @shifts = @search.scope
end
```

And my ShiftSearch model:

```
class ShiftSearch

  attr_reader :date_from, :date_to

  def initialize(params)
    params ||= {}
    @date_from = parsed_date(params[:date_from], 30.days.ago.to_date.strftime("%d/%m/%y").to_s)
    @date_to = parsed_date(params[:date_to], Date.tomorrow.strftime("%d/%m/%y").to_s)
  end

  def scope
    Shift.where('check_in_date BETWEEN ? AND ?', @date_from, @date_to)
  end


  private

  def parsed_date(date_string, default)
    Date.parse(date_string)
  rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
    default
  end
end
```

I can see with byebug in the shifts_search action that the params are correct. However the query sent to my database when I submit the form are incorrect, the query it sends every time is:

```
(byebug) params
#<ActionController::Parameters {"search"=>{"date_from"=>"14/11/21", "date_to"=>"15/12/21"}, "commit"=>"Search", "controller"=>"admin", "action"=>"shifts_search"} permitted: false>
(byebug) continue
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering admin/shifts_search.html.erb within layouts/application
  Shift Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "shifts".* FROM "shifts" WHERE (check_in_date BETWEEN '2014-11-21' AND '2015-12-21')
  ↳ app/views/admin/shifts_search.html.erb:13
  Rendered admin/shifts_search.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 3.1ms | Allocations: 1307)
```

Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ruby DateTime parsing from 'mm/dd/yyyy' format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643444/ruby-datetime-parsing-from-mm-dd-yyyy-format)

Comment: `Date.strptime("14/11/21", "%d/%m/%y")`

Comment: I think using a date_field_tag instead of text would make it much easier.